# Laravel Envoy Error: Too many arguments, expected arguments "command"

Tags: laravel-envoy

I started using Envoy. But I'm getting some errors

```
@servers(['web' => '127.0.0.1'])

@story('deploy')
    git
    artisan
@endstory

@task('git')
    git pull origin master
@endtask

@task('artisan')
    php artisan migrate
@endtask
```

This works fine for me. But If add some more commands to each task like

```
@servers(['web' => '127.0.0.1'])

@story('deploy')
    git
    artisan
@endstory

@task('git')
    git pull origin master
@endtask

@task('artisan')
    php artisan migrate
    php artisan db:seed
@endtask
```

It stops working and I get errors Too many arguments, expected arguments "command". I added one another command to artisan task(last task)

Comment: I tried many ways changed the name of the tasks, re order the commands in the tasks. Use semi-colon. but no luck

Comment: The second one works fine for me.

Comment: Show exact error test, please.

Answer (score 1):

Run this by...

```
envoy run deploy
```

And if you want to avoid prompts just add `--force`.

```
@setup
    $ip = '127.0.0.1'
@endsetup

@servers(['local' => $ip])

@story('deploy')
    git
    artisan
@endstory

@task('git')
    git pull origin master
@endtask

@task('artisan')
    php artisan migrate --force
    php artisan db:seed --force
@endtask
```